# How to write to a JSON Column in BigQuery using Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, spark-bigquery-connector

I have a dataframe which contains a JSON String as a `StringType` Column. How can you write this to BigQuery JSON Column (New Feature)? Spark JSON Write to BigQuery with examples is not available https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

When we try to write the string in append Mode to a JSON Column we get an error

`Field source has changed type from JSON to STRING`

According to  [Readme -> Datatypes -> JSON](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#data-types)

How this can be implemented with an example

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#:~:text=issues%20as%20DATETIME-,JSON,-StringType)
The DataFrame field MUST be of type String and has an entry of sqlType=JSON in its metadata for two JSON columns "id" & "data"

Comment: `val table_schema = new StructType()
.add(StructField("id", StringType, true, Metadata.fromJson("""{"sqlType":"JSON"}""")))
.add(StructField("data", StringType, true, Metadata.fromJson("""{"sqlType":"JSON"}""")))`
`val df_bigquery = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, table_schema`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark BigQuery Connector usage for JSON is mentioned in their [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#:%7E:text=JSON,StringType)

Spark has no JSON type. The values are read as String. In order to
write JSON back to BigQuery, the following conditions are REQUIRED
Use the INDIRECT write method
Use the AVRO intermediate format
The DataFrame field MUST be of type String and has an entry of sqlType=JSON in its metadata

I had raised an issue for clarification which can be found here [#880](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/880) and [#882](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/882)

In the below Scala Spark example, I have a table, that contains two JSON columns `metadata` & `data`. Here we first create a `table_schema` metadata and then we assign the schema metadata to the Spark RDD as follows. Further, we can write directly to the JSON columns in BigQuery using Scala Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{Metadata, StringType, StructField, StructType}

    val table_schema = new StructType()
      .add(StructField(metadata, StringType, true, Metadata.fromJson({sqlTypeJSON})))
      .add(StructField(data, StringType, true, Metadata.fromJson({sqlTypeJSON})))

     Create a BigQuery Dataframe from the RDD and Schema above
    val df_bigquery = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, table_schema)

     Write to BigQuery using Spark BigQuery Connector
     For JSON Column ingestion, writeMethod should be indirect with a temporaryGcsBucket and intermediateFormat as avro
     Target Table Details are provided in spark.datasource.bigquery.full_load_table
     This has two modes, where spark.datasource.bigquery.write.mode can be either overwrite or append
    df_bigquery.write
      .format(bigquery)
      .option(temporaryGcsBucket, 'temp-bucket-name'
      .option(writeMethod, indirect)
      .option(intermediateFormat, avro)
      .mode(append)
      .option(table, 'schema.table')
      .option(createDisposition, CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
      .option(writeDisposition, WRITE_TRUNCATE)
      .save()
  }
```